# Include Statements with PHP do not Access .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When using the Pretty URLS by adding .htaccess tot he root folder, my `<a href="">` links of course do not need the `.php` file extension. However, when I use the PHP `require` or `include`, it throws an error and does not seem to use the .htaccess to add the necessary .php, requiring me to add .php to these statements.

.htaccess

```
# Redirect everything that doesn't match a directory or file to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The .php file in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php require "../Resources/nav.php";?>
        // Main Content
    <?php require "../Resources/footer.php";?>
</body>
```

Does anyone know *why* these statements do not use the .htaccess? Is it just necessary to include file extensions, or is there a way to force them to use .htaccess?

Comment: Includes are not processed by the web server

Comment: @JohnConde Fastest hand in the west. Do includes not have to go back to the server and grab the relevant data/file?

Comment: They do but the web server software (e.g. Apache) doesn't process it since it is not a web request

Comment: How are you including those files? Please add the PHP code to your question. Also, add the error message.

Comment: As @JohnConde said, PHP handles those requests, not Apache and the only way to force Apache to handle them is to require/include files by URL, but,definitely is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Web Server reacts to requests over the network. The RewriteRules are applied only to these requests.

The PHP `require`, `include`, `file_get_contents`, ... functions usually access the local storage instead of issuing a HTTP request to Apache over the network.

While using `file_get_contents` with URLs is possible and sometimes useful, in your use case you have to add the `.php` extension to address the correct local file.